# Having website and facebook login toghether

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I'm creating a website that people can send sms from my website, I want to implement facebook login to my website and any one who logs in to my website using his  facebook account and doesn't have an account in my website i want to create one for him. as he should later enter his phone number and verify the number and without having an account in my website its not possible. now the problem is if I use his facebook username to create the account it might cause duplicate name (as someone else might have got that username).

I will of course combine the information of the existing accounts when someone uses facebook login which have already account in my website. this is not a problem.

what would you suggest?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use the Facebook user name as the `userName` column of your users database. You can get many other unique information from a Facebook user, like e-mail or facebook ID. Use them to "connect" between the information from your database details and the info you receive from Facebook.

For example:

When signing up to your website, one of the fields you can ask is the facebook login e-mail. Thats how a user would have the option to login to your website by Facebook, without any connection between his facebook user name and your user name.

In your user details table, just add a `facebookEmail` column, then, after you implement the Facebook Login API and a user login, check to see if his e-mail (from facebook) is in your table.

Comment: you are right .this is how i intent to combine the accounts. but what should be the username of the account that logs in with facebook. I think leaving it blank till user wants to login from website would be wise. right?

Comment: Give him the option to also choose a username to your site, thats how he will also be able to login by your site and Facebook. In my opinion giving him 2 options to login is better then forcing him for one type of login. If you still want to force a Facebook login, you can render a random string and add it to the unique facebook e-mail - save it as a userName, and you have a unique userName for your table (In that case, the user name doesn't matter to your client, because he will only login by Facebook).

Comment: I'm living in Iran where facebook is filtered and only people who use anti-filters (and they are a lot) can access facebook. so having only facebook login is not an option. there must be website login for those which don't use anti-filters and might not have facebook account.

Comment: I will give him the option to choose a username after he logged in using facebook

Answer (score 0):

> now the problem is if I use his facebook username to create the account it might cause duplicate name (as someone else might have got that username).

Well, then either build in a check if the user name is still free and if not prompt the user to enter a different one; or

automatically chose a different user name, f.e. by using a counter – if the user name from Facebook is *foobar* and this is already taken, then check if *foobar1* is available, etc.

If creating it automatically, maybe you want to give the user the possibility to change it afterwards.